# FieldValue.arrayRemove with DocumentRef as a child

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase collection with a field "timeline" of type array were I save  timeline activity objects of the kind:

const timelineEntry = {
type: 'post',
user: snap.data().postUser,
post: snap.ref,
createdAt: snap.data().timePosted
};

Im adding without problem but when I need to remove an item from the array it doesn't work and I got no error at all. Like it is just not finding the item to remove (I know I have to pass exactly all the fields values to match)

Im executing this on cloud functions on collection  post onCreate and onDelete events.

these are the parameters passed to arrayUnion and arrayRemove from the cloud functions log

{"type":"post","user":{"_firestore":{"projectId":"acme-c580a"},"_path":{"segments":["users","fqV0GztGbfdek5c1FxDZaCHZfXh2"]},"_converter":{}},"post":{"_firestore":{"projectId":"acme-c580a"},"_path":{"segments":["userPosts","89kgGIxl8DsACMRchbxd"],"projectId":"acme-c580a","databaseId":"(default)"},"_converter":{}},"createdAt":{"_seconds":1682047428,"_nanoseconds":474999000}}

{"type":"post","user":{"_firestore":{"projectId":"acme-c580a"},"_path":{"segments":["users","fqV0GztGbfdek5c1FxDZaCHZfXh2"]},"_converter":{}},"post":{"_firestore":{"projectId":"acme-c580a"},"_path":{"segments":["userPosts","89kgGIxl8DsACMRchbxd"],"projectId":"acme-c580a","databaseId":"(default)"},"_converter":{}},"createdAt":{"_seconds":1682047428,"_nanoseconds":474999000}}

They are identical so I don't know what is going on.. could it be that arrayRemove doesn't support passing an object with DocumentReference fields?

this is the object im trying to delete  from the array

[image]

I have read almost all the documentation about FieldValue and I dint find any limitation on the data types allowed and I have validated many times the values passed to both functions are identical.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the client SDK as the data is added and removed as expected. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem using Functions and the Admin SDK?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue partially with just strings as a value in place of reference which you can check [**here**](https://codefile.io/f/6EzKiRBg3yXhVcuAF6P2) so you can store the reference path which will be string instead of reference itself. Although I am also trying to work with reference too.